# React typescript app logs an error: WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:64234/ws' failed

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-typescript

I am getting this error on the console of a react app, but I am not sure why? I am not using any websocket, and I am thinking if it is any package that requires websocket, and is it failing? I know the picture does not say much, but it is a starting point. I have being trying to debug, and react-scripts I think has something to do with it, but not sure why and how. Any help or hint where to look further would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: are you using http or https !?

Comment: i am using https